# Can you add a derived constraint using auto layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

In mechanical CAD software which uses concepts similar to autolayout constraints, you can often add a 'derived constraint'.  This has no effect on the layout, but will allow you to directly read the value of an important dimension.

For example, consider the following layout for a view with two subviews:

```
     32       64
  |------| |------|

|-[imgOne]-[imgTwo]-|

|-------------------|
          w
```

The width of the view is the sum of the default edge spacing on the left and right, the default spacing between image views, and the two width constraints (32 and 64) applied to the image views.

I would like to know `w` at runtime.

In theory, this should be `view.bounds`.  However, it's not always safe to read that property (as the view may not have updated its layout constraints yet).

Is it possible to add a constraint which has no effect on the view size, but which will have its `.constant` property updated once the layout is complete?

(I have tried adding a width constraint to the view with a priority of `1`, but `.constant` always reads the nominal value, instead of the actual value.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "derived" constraint will put you in the same hole you began in--waiting for Auto Layout to finish laying out your views. It's all about timing. When using Auto Layout, a good place to read the final geometries of your views is in your view controller's viewDidLayoutSubviews method. In other words, read the bounds of the view in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Even if it does put you in the same hole - and it definitely could, depending how it's implemented - I'm still hoping for a way to avoid accessing bounds directly, as that seems like a step backwards when *everything else* is in terms of constraints.